# Get the value by key in a multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I am trying to get a certain value from my array, but I'm having some trouble. This is a part of my array code:

```
<?php
$arr = array($plan_data);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

This returns an array like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [_edit_lock] => 1434039341:1 
            [_edit_last] => 1 
            [plan_title] = Membership1 
        )
    )
)
```

How can I store a value of a certain key into a variable?
I tried it like this but this is not working:

```
$key= '[plan_title]'; //also tried $key= 'plan_title';
echo $arr[$key];
```

How can I get the value of the key 'plan_title'?

Comment: `echo $arr[0][$key];` It's in a subarray.

Comment: Thank you `$key= 'ID';
echo $arr[0][$key]; ` worked!

Answer (score 0):

To display try:

```
echo $arr[0][0];
```

To assign a variable try:

```
$variable = $arr[0]['key'];
```

To display all try:

```
foreach($arr = $var)
{
    echo $var;
}
```